# How to install a specific version of a ClearLinux bundle?

Tags: docker, clear-linux

From my understanding one of the main points of Clear Linux is they want it to be easy to reproduce a specific version of the OS.

If that is correct, then how can I install a specific version of a bundle?

E.g. If I install the `ruby-basic` bundle, as seen below, I get the bundle ID, but `swupd` can't take it as an argument.

```
# swupd bundle-add ruby-basic
swupd-client bundle adder 3.10.0
   Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Intel Corporation

Attempting to download version string to memory
Downloading packs...
Extracting ruby-basic pack for version 16880
Installing bundle(s) files...
Calling post-update helper scripts.
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Bundle(s) installation done.
# swupd 
Usage:
    swupd [OPTION...]
 or swupd [OPTION...] SUBCOMMAND [OPTION...]

Help Options:
   -h, --help              Show help options
   -v, --version           Output version information and exit

Subcommands:
   autoupdate              Enable/disable automatic system updates
   bundle-add              Install a new bundle          
   bundle-remove           Uninstall a bundle            
   bundle-list             List installed bundles        
   hashdump                Dumps the HMAC hash of a file 
   update                  Update to latest OS version   
   verify                  Verify content for OS version 
   check-update            Checks if a new OS version is available
   search                  Search Clear Linux for a binary or library

To view subcommand options, run `swupd SUBCOMMAND --help'
```

Btw. This post ought to have a `clearlinux` tag, but I don't have the reputation...

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to the 16880, that number refers to the version of the whole OS.

BTW, the current version of Clear 18080, includes ruby 2.4.0